# JavaScript Regex - Replace a custom tag inside a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say we have the following string:

```
<p>Hello, I am a cool string.</p>
<p>Here I want to show an image: {{ img("path/to/file.jpg", "Title Text") }}</p>
```

The result should look:

```
<p>Hello, I am a cool string.</p>
<p>Here I want to show an image: <img src="path/to/file.jpg" alt="Title Text" /></p>
```

I know, I can do this with javascripts string replace function with regex, but not really how to do it. Basically something like this:

```
string.replace(/???/g, '<img src="$1" alt="$2" />');
```

But I can't find the right regex, since I am a regex newbie :(

`{{ img\((.*)\) }}` will find the img-code, but how to filter the attributes out?

I am writing a TinyMCE plugin which should work similar like the bb-code plugin, but with custom, non bb-code syntax.

Comment: Are you sure regexes are the right tool for the job?

Comment: If you tell me an alternative, I would be happy to use it ;).

Comment: Consider using e.g. KnockoutJS or AngularJS. You seem to want to do templating.

Comment: Eyegropram's and anubhava's answers are correct. Btw. I need this for a tinymce plugin similar to https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/plugins/bbcode/plugin.js so regex is the tool of choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var str = '<img src="path/to/file.jpg" alt="Title Text" />';
var exp = /<.*img.*"(.*)".*"(.*)".*>/g;
var newStr = str.replace(exp,'<img src="$1" alt="$2" />');
console.log(newStr);
```

This matching more towards your example should help to figure out the pattern that will work best for your needs.

```
var str2 = '<p>Here I want to show an image: {{ img("path/to/file.jpg", "Title Text") }}</p>';
var exp2 = /{{.*img.*"(.*)".*"(.*)".*}}/g;
var newStr2 = str2.replace(exp2,'<img src="$1" alt="$2" />');
console.log(newStr2);
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your post. I don't want to replace <img> tag to <img> tag.

Comment: Your code isn't what I am asking, but I gave you +1, since your regex helped me to find the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps this is closer to what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var s = '<p>Here I want to show an image: {{ img("path/to/file.jpg", "Title Text") }}</p>';

var r = s.replace( /{{ img\( *"([^"]+)" *, *"([^"]+)" *\) *}}/g, 
  '<img src="$1" alt="$2" />' );
//=> <p>Here I want to show an image: <img src="path/to/file.jpg" alt="Title Text" /></p>
```

Comment: Works great, but I really need to have separete ", since I need to add some string to the url, something like s.replace( /{{ img\(*([^,]+), *([^)]+)\) *}}/g, '<img src="http://www.example.com/$1" alt="$2" />' );. How can I do this?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! eyeprogram was a little bit faster, so I selected his answer as correct, but yours is also working.

Comment: It is always OP's decision to choose what is best but about faster, are you sure about it? Just mouse over both answers and you will see my answer was more than 9 minutes faster than him.